# How do I retrive files using an internet connection and commands?

Tags: ftp, file-server

I am attempting to download a folder where it has 777 permissions as well as its subfolders, but when I try to use get in ftp, It brings back the error:
550 Failed to open file
Iv'e checked the permissions:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm/4$ ls -l
total 1748
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu     164 Jul  5 09:21 brianThread.hpp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1741092 Jul  5 09:21 brianThread.hpp.gch
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu    9239 Jul  3 13:58 brianThread.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu    9147 Jul  5 09:48 main
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu     236 Jul  5 19:46 main.cpp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu    9147 Jul  5 19:46 main.out
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm/4$ cd ..
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm$ ls
1  2  3  4  5
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm$ cd ..
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  3 13:59 7-1-15_asm
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev$ cd *
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  3 16:59 1
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  2 16:49 2
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  3 05:06 3
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  5 19:46 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  3 14:00 5
```

Here's what I've tried to copy the files:

```
ftp> cd 7-1-15_asm
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1000         4096 Jul 03 16:59 1
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1000         4096 Jul 02 16:49 2
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1000         4096 Jul 03 05:06 3
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1000         4096 Jul 05 19:46 4
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     1000         4096 Jul 03 14:00 5
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> get 4
local: 4 remote: 4
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Failed to open file.
ftp> get 4 /home/brian
local: /home/brian remote: 4
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Failed to open file.
ftp>
```

What am I doing wrong that prevents me from copying a folder from the ftp server to my computer. Both of the computers are on the same network.

In a summary I want to know how to copy /home/ubuntu/sourceDev/7-1-15_asm/4 (which is a folder) and its contents from the computer with the ftp server to the computer issuing the ftp command. Also what are the minimum permissions I can have on a folder and its contents, while it being still possible to copy it to another computer using the ftp command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP clients aren't particularly good at downloading whole directories.

Try using wftp with its useful "-r" option.  "-l 0" ensures it isnt limited to 5 levels of directory.

```
wget -r -l 0 ftp://user:pass@server.com/7-1-15_asm/4
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message relates to your_local_ filename. You are trying to download `4` to the target `/home/brian`. However that target already exists - it's a directory.